# Awesome-WM restrict client size

Tags: awesome-wm

Is it possible in Awesome-WM to restrict a client window, namely my IM contact list, to a specific size?

Answer (score 8):

you need to make the window floating, so it is ignogrd in the tiling layouts. 
Adding this to the suggestion above:

```
-- [...]
{
    rule = { class = "your-app-class-here" },
    properties = { floating = true },
    callback = function( c )
                   c:geometry( { width = 200 , height = 800 } )
               end
},
-- [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule in your `rc.lua` in the table `awful.rules.rules`, for example:

```
-- [...]
{
    rule = { class = "your-app-class-here" },
    callback = function( c )
                   c:geometry( { width = 200 , height = 800 } )
               end
},
-- [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work for me. No matter what application I use for the class or what dimensions I put in, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: My bad, it DOES work. The extra height in your example extended below the bottom of my screen so I didn't see it.  This doesn't do what I thought it would, however.  When I go through the different layouts my contact list size changes anyway.